# Где взять библиотеку javax.sound.sampled?

Tags: java, android

Требуется генерировать звуковые волны.
В примерах предлагается использовать библиотеку javax.sound.sampled.
Где ее можно взять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта библиотека должна входить в состав jdk.

Сейчас проверил: да, она там и лежит.

Попробуйте написать `import javax.sound.sampled.*;` и сможете её использовать, если у вас, конечно, установлен jdk.